# Wifi Direct Cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, wifi, cordova-plugins, wifi-direct

I am trying create an app using cordova, I needed to use wifi to transfer data to another app, I searched a lot, i found many plugins which is used to scan , connect and create network, set ssid and other major stuffs, i didnt find a plugin which supports Writing a data via wifi, is there any way to do this, or any plugin which i may not have come across, Kindly i need an way to do this.

I am open to suggestions such as using socket or p2p communications. I dont want to do this in BLE.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean by 'Writing a data via wifi'? Are you thinking about two way communications between two devices, i which you will be sending data ?

Comment: yep, exactly i am speaking about two way communication

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information).

Usage example:

```
if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.WIFI) {
    alert('Connection type: ' + states[navigator.connection.type]);
}
```

Comment: I need to write data using Wifi